# Invalid Date error trying to parse a string containing AM or PM using npm date-and-time library in javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

i get invalid date error trying to parse a string containing PM or AM with time-and-date, here is my code:

```
const date = require('date-and-time');

let d = date.parse('Dec, 25 2019 at 3:51 AM', 'MMM, D YYYY at h:m A');

//same error with following line also
//let d = date.parse('Dec, 25 2019 at 3:51 AM', 'MMM, D YYYY at h:m AA (*)');

console.log(d);
```

result:

```
Invalid Date
```

i'm referencing their document here: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-and-time/v/0.11.1

the page has following lines in the document, i wonder if I misunderstood them:

```
  A         meridiem    a.m., p.m.
  a (*)     meridiem    A.M., P.M.
  AA (*)    meridiem    AM, PM
  aa (*)    meridiem    am, pm
```

Comment: That page shows `a.m.` and `p.m.`, not `AM` or `PM`.

Comment: added to the question, the page documentation includes AM PM if i understand correctly

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, as @ChrisG commented, that you are using `AM`/`PM` instead of `a.m.`/`p.m.`.

It works when using the latter, see [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-sun-4cwb4) sandbox.

EDIT:

If you want to use AM/PM, you should either create a feature request on that package or switch to another package (moment, for instance)

Comment: thank you - Yes, i need to use PM or AM. I can't use a.m or p.m since the original text is out of my control. I can replace AM and PM with a.m./p.m. programmatically before parsing but that seems sloppy to me

Comment: Then you should maybe look for another date time package, or, as you say, replace AM/PM with a.m./p.m.

Comment: Or, create a feature request to the package